# Scrolling between view controllers Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, swipe

im trying to create an App where you have 3 view controllers and you can swipe between them using a scroll view.

I managed to have 2 views working perfectly but when I tried to add a third it just replaced the second.

Here is the code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ChatsViewController *aViewController = [[ChatsViewController alloc]init];
    [self addChildViewController:aViewController];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:aViewController.view];
    [aViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    FriendsViewController *bViewController = [[FriendsViewController alloc]init];
    CGRect frame = bViewController.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 320;
    bViewController.view.frame = frame;

    ProfileView *cViewController = [[ProfileView alloc]init];
    CGRect frame2 = cViewController.view.frame;
    frame2.origin.x = 640;
    cViewController.view.frame = frame;

    [self addChildViewController:bViewController];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:bViewController.view];
    [bViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self addChildViewController:cViewController];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:cViewController.view];
    [cViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    }
```

I'm using this library: https://github.com/gneil90/CustomContainerViewController

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
cViewController.view.frame = frame
```

should be

```
cViewController.view.frame = frame2
```

Comment: well this is embarrassing ;) I guess its time to go to sleep. Thank you very much!